# Change Google Marker Size After Zoom Make the Markers Rendered twice with Different Size

Tags: javascript, google-maps-markers

We are using google map through angularjs' NgMap. The markers need to be circle, and handle click event. So we are using google.maps.Circle. When zoom in, the marker grows quickly and could be very big. It is able to prevent this by add listener to map zoom change:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function (markers, newRadius) {
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
        marker.setRadius(newRadius);
    });
});
```

But the problem is that there are a collection of markers, it seems like the map repaints with markers' former size before this change first, and then update the markers with the new size. That means the map repainted twice after change zoom level once.

How to make the markers render only once after zoom? or is it possible to configure the Circle, so when it is painted, its radius to be dertermined by some formula relevant to the zoom level?

Thanks for any help!